# Vtd from an InputStream

Tags: java, vtd-xml

I parse a document using vtd like this

```
VTDGen vtd = new VTDGen();
vtd.setDoc(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
vtd.parse(true);
VTDNav nav = vtd.getNav();
...
```

Is it possible to do this without the intermediary step of converting the `inputStream` to a `byte[]`? I'd like to defer any potential memory management stuff to vtd.

Comment: I'm parsing a document that exists in a zip file - so only have access to the stream in this case.

Comment: Thanks @vtd-xml-author - in my case the zip file isn't something that lives on the filesystem either (it comes to me via a REST POST)